# Force Cache refresh for one container

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, caching

a quick example:

```
<img id="example" source="example.png"> // This is my container in another file

<scipt>
 // Here I execute a php script that changes the image 'example.png'
 $('#example').hide().load('content/content.php #example').show();
</script>
```

After this script is done the picture didn't updated.

Is there a way to force a Cache refresh for #example.

Something like:

```
 <scipt>
 // Here I execute a php script that changes the image 'example.png'
 $('#example').hide().load('content/content.php #example').show();
 // Refresh Cache for #example or execute php(refresh)
</script>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you request url's, you can add `GET` parameters to it, making the browser think its requesting a different page. This makes the browser always download the latest version.

You can try the following. I'm not very good with JQuery myself but I do believe this will work:

```
$.get("content/content.php",{},function(e) {
  // now we update the image since the content.php has finished loading.
  $('#example').attr("src","example.png?e="+(new Date().getTime()));
});
```